# How to play the 2-Player mode?

Tags: pacman-color-edition

On the Pac-Man Special Color Edition game for the Gameboy Color, when selecting the classic game "Pac-Man" it gives you the option to choose 1 or 2 players. When I try choosing two players, the cursor will immediately move back to the single player option.

So how do I play 2 Player? Do I need to link a two Gameboys together that both have the game? Or just two Gameboys together? Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is actually one of the games compatible with the GameCube - which is how you play multiplayer

Comment: @Ben No, this game is for the Gameboy Color, not the Gameboy Advance.